# My Microsoft Wireless Mouse 2000 Stops Working When I Lift It Up

Tags: troubleshooting, wireless-mouse

When I turn my mouse on I have to put it on a flat surface right away for the blue light to stay on underneath which I'm guessing is the laser to detect surfaces. Once I lift my mouse up for more than a second, the light turns off and it does not come back on when I put it back on the surface. I have to turn off and turn it back on every single time that happens. If anybody might know a solution to this it would be kindly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar mouse (the 3500 model). This doesn't happen to my mouse.

You probably have a hardware defect. If your mouse is still under warranty, consider having it replaced.